# Removing a floating (jquery draggable) DIV from DOM causes its Siblings (DIVs) to climb up

Tags: html, move

Say I have two floated div's inside a fixed parent div. The div's were made to float
using JQuery draggable. When I remove the first DIV from the DOM, the second DIV below it,
for some reason seems to climb up the page.

I've created a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/k6yxu/1/

In this example when you close box 1, box 2 moves up. This happens in Chrome, Firefox and IE 9.

I want to keep all these boxes (DIVs) the same place, even when any of its siblings are removed from DOM.

```
<style>
html, body, #container {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 13px;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
}
#header, #footer {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background: #999;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
#header {
    top: 0;
}
#footer {
    bottom: 0;
}
/* This is the parent of inner-content div */
 #content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    border-top: 1px solid #888;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
/* This is the direct parent of all boxes */
 #inner-content {
    overflow: inherit;
    height: 100%;
}
.box {
    border: 4px solid #999;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
}
.boxHeader {
    height: 32px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.boxCloseButton {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 13px;
    cursor: pointer
}
</style>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="headerContent"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="inner-content">
            <div id="id0" class="box">
                <div class="boxHeader">
                    <div class="boxHeaderContent">1 <span><a class="boxCloseButton">x</a></span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="id1" class="box">
                <div class="boxHeader">
                    <div class="boxHeaderContent">2 <span><a class="boxCloseButton">x</a></span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".box").each(function () {
        $(this).draggable({
            containment: "#inner-content",
            scroll: true
        });
    });

    $(document).on("click", "a.boxCloseButton", function () {
        // Close button is clicked
        // get the parent div box
        var box = $(this).parents('div.box');
        // remove box from DOM. 
        // BUG: Removing a node from the DOM causes all its younger siblings to be re-positioned.
        // The re-positioning is random and causes un-expected behaviour.
        box.remove();
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the boxes absolute positioned: http://jsfiddle.net/k6yxu/2/

```
.box {
    position: absolute;
    border: 4px solid #999;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
}
#id1 {
    top:124px;
}
```

If you want to avoid the `top` positioning, you will need to wrap each box in a `position: relative` container, and only remove the `.box`, leaving the container. That container will also need the proper height set.

**Edit:** Here is a fiddle with said adjustments: http://jsfiddle.net/k6yxu/3/

Answer (score 0):

> When I remove the first DIV from the DOM, the second DIV below it, for
>   some reason seems to climb up the page.

Isn't that the definition of float?

Comment: By float I meant draggable. And once I drag and drop it off some place, I'd expect the DIV to stick to that place. If it starts to move on its own, the behavior seems incorrect.